# How to keep RecyclerView from scrolling when softkeyboard shows up with adjustResize set?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app has an `Activity` that's declared with:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

`adjustResize` is set and in that activity I have a `RecyclerView` and an `EditText` as in a chat like app.

The problem I'm facing is that when the keyboard shows up the layout is resized as intented but it also scrolls up the `RecyclerView` contents.

The behavior desired is that the scroll stays put.

I've tried using `LayoutManager#onSaveInstanceState()` and it's counterpart `LayoutManager#onRestoreInstanceState()` with no avail.

I know many had similar/same issues but I couldn't find a good solutions for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, amazing how a clear head and a sudden glimpse of thought makes wonders.

I don't know about everyone but I haven't found a solution for this simple problem this way, and it works for me. Sharing:

```
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, bottom, _, _, _, oldBottom ->
    val y = oldBottom - bottom
    val firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
    if (y.absoluteValue > 0 && !(y < 0 && firstVisibleItem == 0)) {
        recycler_view.scrollBy(0, y)
    }
}
```

Only drawback so far is that when you're scrolled to the second item and you hide the soft keyboard, it scrolls to the very end but no big deal for me.

Hope it helps someone.

**EDIT**:
Here's how I solved without any drawbacks now:

```
private var verticalScrollOffset = AtomicInteger(0)

recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, bottom, _, _, _, oldBottom ->
    val y = oldBottom - bottom
    if (y.absoluteValue > 0) {
        // if y is positive the keyboard is up else it's down
        recyclerView.post {
            if (y > 0 || verticalScrollOffset.get().absoluteValue >= y.absoluteValue) {
                recyclerView.scrollBy(0, y)
            } else {
                recyclerView.scrollBy(0, verticalScrollOffset.get())
            }
        }
    }
}

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    var state = AtomicInteger(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        state.compareAndSet(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, newState)
        when (newState) {
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                if (!state.compareAndSet(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING, newState)) {
                    state.compareAndSet(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, newState)
                }
            }
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                state.compareAndSet(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, newState)
            }
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING -> {
                state.compareAndSet(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, newState)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        if (state.get() != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            verticalScrollOffset.getAndAdd(dy)
        }
    }
})
```

**EDIT2**: This can be easily converted to Java if that's your poison.

Comment: Works perfectly.
(Thanks man, I was stuck for a whole day with this problem, spinning womehere around your solution but couldn't get right to it.)

Comment: The only important think I've chnaged to avoid drifting bug with scroll state switch is that I've simplified method 
`override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) { state.set(newState) }`.

Answer (score 0):

use addOnscrollListener to check weather currently recyclerview is at bottom or not
if yes then use the method provided in accepted answer by doing it youe recycler only scroll when last item is visible else it wont scroll

```
recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            cannotScrollVertically = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);//use a Boolean variable
        }
    });
```